# Clickhouse - OOM - When the function of Clickhouse data import is executed, the program is killed by the system

Tags: database, clickhouse

When I was performing the `Clickhouse` data import function, the program was killed by the system.

The execution command is as follows:
`clickhouse-client --user default --password xxxxx --port 9000 -hxxx --database="bds" --input_format_allow_errors_ratio=0.1 --query="insert into ... FORMAT CSV" < /1.csv`

The error reported is:
`[2478416.927226] Out of memory: Kill process 19696 (clickhouse-serv) score 12 or sacrifice child [2478416.928855] Killed process 19696 (clickhouse-serv), UID 0, total-vm:46668916kB, anon-rss:1008480kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB`

Data file has 122g, server memory 128G, how to let the `Clickhouse` command to reasonable import it, I hope you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most probably it's a bug. What CH version do you use?

Try to add parameters `--input_format_parallel_parsing=0 --optimize_on_insert=0`

```
--input_format_parallel_parsing arg                              Enable parallel parsing for some data formats.

--optimize_on_insert arg                                         Do the same transformation for inserted block of data as if merge was done on this block.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try. My `Clickhouse` version is `21.4.3.21`